# Display search results while typing AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do some kind of live search with ajax to show a list of users while typing in a search bar.
I'm struggling to return the data and display it in my view.

what I've tried so far:

**My JQuery script:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        const base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
        $("#search_user").keyup(function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            const val = $(this).value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url + "/public/Friendcontroller/search", // the method we are calling
                data: {search:val},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    response(result);
                    console.log("Success",result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    console.error("unsuccessful",result);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

**My controller function and model function:**

*Controller search function*

```
public function search(): array
    {
       return $this->friend_model->liveSearch($_POST['search']);
    }
```

*Model function*

```
public function liveSearch($val) {
        $search = array();
        $result = $val;

        $getUser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName LIKE '%$result%' OR firstName LIKE '%$result%'
                        OR lastName LIKE '%$result%'";

        $query = $this->db->query($getUser);

        foreach ($query->getResult() as $row) {
            $userID = $row->userID;
            $firstName = $row->firstName;
            $lastName = $row->lastName;
            $userName = $row->userName;
            $avatar = $row->avatarUrl;
            array_push($search, array('userID' => $userID, 'firstName' => $firstName,
                'lastName' => $lastName, 'userName' => $userName, 'avatarUrl' => $avatar));
        }
        return $search;
    }
```

**The HTML where I want to render the results:**

```
<div style="height: 32px"></div>
    <?php foreach (//Result from AJAX call here): ?>
        <div class="tabs-stage">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="person">
                    <div class="personHead">
                        <div class="profile">
                            <img id="avatar" class="head3" src="<?=base_url()?>/public/uploads/avatars/<?=$result['avatarUrl']?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="personName">
                            <h2><?= $result['userName'] ?></h2>
                            <h4><?= $result['firstName'] . " " . $result['lastName'] ?></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You need to take your results in the `success` handler and place the contents inside the element where you want them. Currently it doesn't seem you're doing anything like that. What is `response(result)` supposed to achieve?

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: @El_Vanja I tried it this way (which obviously didn't work) after searching on the internet

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 I get an Unsuccessful error in the console

Answer (score 0):

I think you should either return the array json encoded or "build" and return an html string to append it where ever you want on *success*

If you return an html string then you can do this on success

```
success: function (result) {
                $("your div").html(result);
                console.log("Success",result);
            }
```

If you return json `return json_encode($search);` then you must iterate over each row and create/append the elements you want.

Comment: I changed my controller function to ```return json_encode``` and i still have an Unsuccessful error in my console

Comment: oh maybe the problem is on the `const val = $(this).value;`. It should be either `const val = $(this)[0].value;` or `const val = $(this).val();`

Comment: also i think you should echo the result, not return it (in function search() )

Answer (score 0):

You cant use php in the html anymore because it already has been run serverside,

you have to rebuild the html with javascript, something like:

```
success: function (result) {
    var $container = $('#resultContainer');
    $.each(result,function(i,res){
        $container.append('<div class="person"><h2>'+res.userName+'</h2></div>');
    });
},
```

Comment: I'm confused because I only showed a small piece of my HTML but what I used to do was to pass data to my view with PHP e.g an array of people you are already friends with, people you sent a request to and show different buttons depending on the friendship status. This, I'm doing with PHP ```if```-statements in my view but how will I replace all those ```if```'s when using AJAX to still have the desired result?

Comment: when you use ajax you are actually passing the data with javascript to html, php is only run on the serverside, so either you return the generated html string from server or you build it up based on the data in javascript on the clientside.